# iOS Longpress to select text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I am building a simple table based search app. The user can ofcourse search through keyboard. But I also want to have another mode of search.

Say a user `longpress` on a `UILabel` then based on where the press is happening, that word should get selected & search should happen (no keyboard) on that word.

I know how to detect `longpress` events but does anyone know how to copy, detect & access the exact term where the `longpress` has occurred?

**UPDATE**: I am aware that I can get the object where `longpress` occurred from which I can get the content of the label text. But I need the exact word on top of which the finger was placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing easy comes to mind for `UILabel` or `UITextView`. If you're wiling to lay the text out yourself with Core Text, then you can pretty easily find words near the touch. The trouble with that is you'd lose the existing selection features of `UILabel` and have to reimplement them (or do "shadow layout" in Core Text hoping things will lay out identically in the `UILabel`... slowly descending into madness here.)

Rather than going down this rabbit hole, I'd recommend using the standard text selection mechanism and add "search" to the [menu](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just put a UILongPressGestureRecognizer on your label then when the gesture recognizer fires you can access which object it came from and read the label value from there.

```
myLongPressRecognizer.view
```

Comment: but the label value might include an entire sentence. I want the exact word that the user tapped on... is that possible?

Comment: but the label value might include an entire sentence. I want the exact word that the user places his/her finger on... is that possible?